# Solving an ODE with factors that span over orders of magnitude in the region of interest with PINN

Tags: neural-networks, math, loss, problem-solving

I am trying to solve the following ordinary differential equation (ODE) with a physics informed neural network (PINN)

$$
\frac{dZ}{dx} = A(x) (1-Z^2) \exp(-Z) - B(x) 
$$
where A(x) function varies in many orders of magnitude in the region of x under consideration. The initial condition of this ODE is $Z(x_{\rm in}) = 0$ and the numerical solution using classical methods of solving this ODE shows that Z(x) is very close to 0 at the beginning and starts to deviate from 0 significantly after a certain value of x.

The problem is that the contributions to the loss function for this PINN:

```
def get_pde_loss(t, t0):
 Z = my_pinn(t0)
 # initial condition
 loss1 = (torch.squeeze(Z))**2

 Y = my_pinn(t)
 # ODE
 dZdt = torch.autograd.grad(Z, t, torch.ones_like(Y), create_graph=True)[0]
 loss2 = torch.mean(( dZdt - A(t)*(1 - Z**2)/torch.exp(Z) + B(t) )**2)

 lambda1 = 1e-3
 loss = loss1 + lambda1*loss2
 return loss
```

vary by many orders of magnitude in different points of x. As far as I understand, this creates a problem for the backpropagation and the algorithm cannot succeed to approximate the solution in a reasonable time.

Is there a general approach to tackle this kind of ODEs (e.g. a different method to construct the loss function) where factors vary over many orders of magnitude?